# How to put the same footnote/watermark to the right in every single page of a document?

Tags: footnotes, alignment, watermark

I'm looking for something like this, where HERE is where the text will be.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This can be done with `eso-pic`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish. `\usepackage{lipsum}` is just to have some text. If you want a grid to guide the eye, use e.g. `\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=black!30,subgridcolor=gray!10]{eso-pic}` instead of `\usepackage{eso-pic}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
     \AtTextLowerLeft{%
         \put(290,-20){\fbox{some text}}%
     }%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]